# Django template extends doens`t open a file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I`m trying to extend one html file from other, but it simply shows me only base.html result.

**Here is my project folders:**

```
-diploma
  -catalogue
    -migrations
    -templates
      -catalogue
        base.html
        header.html
    _init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
  -diploma
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
```

**settings.py**

```
...

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'catalogue',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

...

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from catalogue import views

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
     return render(request, 'catalogue/base.html')
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**header.html**

```
{% extends 'catalogue/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Hello</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Really, trying to find the issue, but can`t figure out. Only effect cghanges made in base.html

Comment: ..because you're rendering the base file?

Comment: omg, dummy... thanks body

Answer (score 0):

Try putting: 
{% extends 'base.html' %}
instead of the whole path